# Default android ttf/otf file for FreeType?

Tags: android, fonts, freetype2

I'm developing a third party keyboard for Android, and for word previous etc, I'm using freetype to render the fonts.

I was wondering if there exists a default ttf/otf file available to be accessed somewhere on the android directories, which I can use instead of having to bundle a 10+ megabyte ttf file (the korean hangul for example was 5 megabytes)?

Comment: Do you want Separate ttf/otf files like these one = http://www.fontspace.com/category/android

Comment: Hmm, I think you might have misunderstood my question. I'm looking to see if android bundles any and puts them somewhere in the system directory, which I can access, so I don't have to bundle any on my app.